# Why am I not getting anything when I break blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can break blocks but they give me nothing in one world. And I don't want to restart because I'm creating an adventure map.

Comment: Are you building the world in Adventure mode or creative/survival?

Comment: If I were to take a guess at the problem it may be because you have gamerule  [/gamerule doTileDrops false]  set to false.  You can check this by typing /gamerule doTileDrops and hitting enter, this will tell you if it's set to true or false.  (This is assuming you are using command/cheats)

Comment: I'm in creative going into survival.

Comment: I'll try that. (:

Comment: @Jason_ I would write that as an answer so you can get credit

Comment: Glad it worked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I were to take a guess at the problem it may be because you have gamerule `/gamerule doTileDrops false` set to false. You can check this by typing `/gamerule doTileDrops` and hitting enter, this will tell you if it's set to true or false. If it says false simply type (true) after the previous command (This is assuming you are using command/cheats)

Answer (score 1):

You said that you were in creative mode.

In creative mode when you break blocks they will not drop an item because you can get the item from your creative inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Go to world settings and go to tile drops. Tile drops doesn't mean that the sand/cobblestone won't fall it means you won't receive the blocks you mine. Turn tile drops ON.

Comment: This is only a world setting in [tag:minecraft-bedrock-edition], but the post is tagged [tag:minecraft-java-edition]. You might want to clarify your answer in regards to that.